# onitemclick listener not working in list view

Tags: android, android-studio

```
  public class EastContent extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
        public static ArrayList j;
        ListView listView;
        String s="sonu";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.east_content);
            Intent iin= getIntent();
            Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
            String[] array={"sonu","monu","ronu","sone"};
            ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
            j=b.getStringArrayList("name");
            listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.customtextview,R.id.textViewcustom,array);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);      
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {        
                 switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"good hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"achha nahi hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"achha cool hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"sdvvgsgvrsg",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }       
      }}
```

Comment: Java's basics: How should looks switch case statement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "break" for each case to stop fall through switch statement.

```
switch(position){
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"good hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
break;
```

... And so on.

Answer (score 1):

You simply forget to make a `break` after `case`:

```
 switch (position){
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"good hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"achha nahi hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"achha cool hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            break;
        case 3:
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"sdvvgsgvrsg",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}}
```

without a `break`, the `switch` is running through all `cases`.